# Run Executable from makefile

Tags: linux, command-line, makefile, executable

Hey I just have a quick question about makefile's. Is there some way to auto run the executable generated from a makefile?

Like if I just type "make" it will compile and build and automatically execute so I can skip the extra step of ./myExecutable

I have down in my notes:

```
run: prog1
        ./prog1
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` - what happens when you type `make run`? Any console output? Any error messages?

Comment: error 127, command not found @AndreasFester

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you run make without specifying any targets, it would execute the first target it finds within the Makefile. By convention `all` is the name of such a target.

If you make `run` a pre-requisite for `all` and mark both `all` and `run` as PHONY targets, you should be good to go.

```
all: run

run: prog1
    ./prog1

.PHONY: all run
```

BTW, I presume you already have some rules for building `prog1` in your Makefile, and hence have not included it in the above shown Makefile.

An alternative would be to just invoke make explicitly with the `run` target, i.e. execute the following command:

```
make run
```

Comment: Yeah I had rules for building. I didn't think it was necessary to add my makefile code since it was a quick question. But thanks! works like a charm.