# Generating a make file which runs executable

Tags: makefile

I tried to run an execuatble after refering to some link on SO [Run Executable from makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566405/run-executable-from-makefile). Everything works fine only that I need to type **"make run"** to execute all commands. I want to know how can I run it without having to type run and simply make should run everything. As of now make command only executes the rule all and to run the other part I have to use make run. I am new to Make. Could you also help me refine the code a little. Any help is appreciated.

```
all:    rdata.c
    -sudo rm a.out
    -gcc rdata.c -o a.out

exec:   run

run:    all
    -sudo ./a.out
    sudo javac -classpath /home/hduser/12115_Select_Query/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar -d mysort MySort.java 
    sudo jar -cvf mysort.jar -C mysort/ .
    -hadoop fs -rmr MySort/output
    -hadoop fs -rmr MySort/input
    hadoop fs -mkdir MySort/input
    hadoop fs -put Data/data.txt MySort/input       
    hadoop jar mysort.jar org.myorg.MySort MySort/input MySort/output
    -sudo rm /home/hduser/Out/sort.txt
    hadoop fs -copyToLocal MySort/output/part-r-00000 /home/hduser/Out/sort.txt
    sudo gedit /home/hduser/Out/sort.txt

.PHONY: exec run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `run` rule first, before `all`.

You can also rewrite the `all` rule and rename it, to reduce redundancy and handle the dependencies correctly:

```
run: a.out
    blah blah blah

a.out: rdata.c
    -sudo rm $@
    -gcc $< -o $@
```

(I don't know enough about java and hadoop to judge the `run` rule.)

Comment: Hey. Thanks. It works. I want to know more about the redundancies occurring here. Also is it that make only runs the first rule defined in the Makefile?

Comment: @RED When run without arguments make uses the default target. Without being told anything special the default target is the first target make finds in the makefile.

Comment: @RED: You could also leave the `run` rule where it was and put `.DEFAULT_GOAL := run` somewhere in the makefile, but I wanted to give the simplest answer that works.